# Yiiframework can't load js & css resource

Tags: yii, centos5

I have my Yii application worked well on Windows Server.
But when I deploy it on Centos server, the js and css files cannot be loaded.
I got 404 error, CHttpException.

```
Source code to load resource:
     Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/css/custom.css');
     Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js');
```

In addition, I have 4 Yii web applications deploy on the same server. And the other ones work well.
Does anyone know the reason why? Can it be a security error on Centos that does not publish themes folder?

Please help me on this.

TIA,

Comment: Did you check what `Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/css/custom.css'` resolves to?

Comment: It resolve to "http://mydomain/themes/classic/css/custom.css". by the way, I could not access http://mydomain/themes/ from my browser.

Comment: So find out why that won't work as a URL and fix it.

Comment: could be something with your .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's permissions problem. Check permissions of your files and folders (can web-server process access them)

Comment: I compared the permissions between 2 apps (this failed app and a working app), and they are the same. Except for the problem that I can access the themes folder of the working web app from my browser. But I got the error: "Unable to resolve the request "themes/" when I try to access http://mydomain/themes

Comment: Maybe it's your web-server config. Directory have closed for access

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved. I guess it because of file permission. - The first time I create a folder, copy source file then grant permission for web-server user. It does not work as above. - 2nd time: I create rootdocument, grant permission for web-server user and then copy source, it works.